# Why is the spectrum of $\mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]$ equal to $\mathbb{C}^*$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Can someone help me see why the following is true?: $$\operatorname{Spec}( \mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}])= \mathbb{C}^*$$

It was stated in something I read but I don't know why it is true. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you know how to find $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[X])$?

Comment: @Hurkyl I know that maximal ideals of $k[X_1,\cdots, X_n]$ are in 1-1 correspondence with points of $k^n$, and that $\operatorname{Specmax}(k[X_1,\cdots, X_n]) =\{ (X_1-a_1,\cdots, X_n-a_n) : (a_1,\cdots, a_n)\in k^n\}.$ And I know that prime ideals of $k[X_1,\cdots, X_n]$ are in 1-1 correspondence with irreducible varieties in $k^n.$ So I don't know if this is "finding" it but I think $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[X])$ is the set of $I(V)$ where $I(V)$ is the ideal of polynomials that vanish on the irreducible variety $V$? Can I get a more concrete description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the spectrum of a PID consists of all prime ideals, which are either $0$ or $(p)$ for some prime element $p$. Now $\mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]$ is a PID and the prime elements are those of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ except for associates of $X$. Thus the spectrum consists of $(0)$ and of all $(X-a)$ with $a \in \mathbb{C}^*$. As a set, we have $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]) = \mathbb{C}^* \cup \{\eta\}$, where $\eta$ is the generic point.

More generally (but one doesn't need this here), if $A$ is a commutative ring and $f \in A$, then there is an isomorphism of schemes $\mathrm{Spec}(A_f) \cong D(f)$, where the latter is the open subspace $\{\mathfrak{p} : f \notin \mathfrak{p}\}$ of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$.

Comment: I understand the first sentence. Second sentence: Why is $\mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]$ a PID, and why are it's prime elements the same as those of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ except non-zero multiples of $X$ ? Assuming those, I understand the third sentence. The 0 ideal corresponds to this generic point it seems, but what is the generic point? And is it usually omitted/ignored like it was where I read it?

Comment: So the only thing left is, why do prime elements in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ stay prime in $\mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]$ except the associates of $X$?

Comment: In general the primes of the localization $S^{-1}R$ of a ring are in one-to-one correspondence with the primes of $R$ that do not intersect $S$.  So the primes of $\mathbb C[x, x^{-1}]$ are exactly those primes in $\mathbb C[x]$ that don't contain a power of $x$.